# call pthread_cond_wait without locking mutex

Tags: pthreads, mutex, conditional-statements, wait

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
pthread_cond_t done;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
void*cond_wait(void*p){
while(1){
printf("%dwait\n",(int)p);
pthread_cond_wait(&done,&mutex);
printf("%dwakeup\n",(int)p);
}

}
int main(){
int status;
int i=1;
pthread_t p;
status=pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_cond_init(&done,NULL);
pthread_create(&p,NULL,cond_wait,(void*)1);
while(1){
sleep(1);
pthread_cond_signal(&done);
}
}
```

The thread  just wake up  and  is not blocked by the mutex because it doesn't call call pthread_cond_wait  without locking mutex.Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `pthread_cond_wait()` without the calling thread having already locked the mutex, the program has undefined behaviour.  Anything could happen, including a crash.